# Como gerar números aleatórios em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Eu gostaria de saber como gerar números aleatórios em Python. Estou com a versão 3.4.

Comment: É de muita valia notar que não é possível - ao menos no presente - gerar números aleatórios. O que geramos, quando falamos erroneamente *números aleatórios*, são números **pseudo aleatórios**.

Veja mais aqui https://goo.gl/Vr6tPT e aqui https://goo.gl/2k1Fvg

Comment: Eu já sabia que são pseudo aleatórios, quando estava estudando C. Mas no dia-a-dia, são chamados aleatórios mesmo.

Comment: Daria se abrir o /deve/urandom

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
from random import randint
print(randint(0,9))
```

Isto gera números inteiros entre 0 e 9.

É possível usar diversas outras funções disponíveis na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/random.html). Cada uma pode ser melhor para o que você deseja.

```
from random import randrange, uniform
print(randrange(0, 9)) #faixa de inteiro
print(uniform(0, 9)) #faixa de ponto flutuante
```

Você pode importar tudo e usar o que deseja:

```
from random import *
random.seed() #inicia a semente dos número pseudo randômicos
random.randrange(0, 9, 2) # pares entre 0 e 9
random.choice('abcdefghij') # seleciona um dos elementos aleatoriamente
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
random.shuffle(items) # embaralha os itens aleatoriamente
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Math/Random.py).

Comment: Quando tiver mais reputação, oferecerei alguns pontos de recompensa. Foi bastante útil.

Answer (score 13):

```
from random import *
print random()
print uniform(10,20)
print randint(100,1000)
print randrange(100,1000,2)
```

`random()` retorna um `float` x tal que 0 <= x < 1.

`uniform(10,20)` retorna um `float` x tal que 10 <= x < 20.

`randint(100,1000)` retorna um `inteiro` x tal que 100 <= x < 1000.

`randrange(100,1000,2)` retorna um `inteiro` x tal que 100 <= x < 1000 e x é par

Comment: O que cada um desses códigos faz?

Comment: Atualizado @Mateus Souza

Comment: você sabe que usar  `from xxx import *` não é considerarada uma boa prática, não?  O roblema é que nem quem olha o código, nem ferramentas automáticas (IDEs) tem como saber de onde veio uma dada função que é encontrada no meio do código.

Answer (score 3):

Não consigo comentar ainda por não ter pontuação para isso, mas `randint` inclui o último número, ao contrário de `randrange,` que funciona mais como o resto do Python (intervalo fechado no começo e aberto no fim). Logo, na resposta do lai0n, `randint(100,1000)` inclui o 1000 nas possibilidades. 
   Pelo menos no Python 3.4, que é o que uso. Logo, `randrange(a, b+1)` é o mesmo que `randint(a, b)`

Answer (score 2):

Deixo aqui uma função como sugestão, que gera números aleatórios (de 0.0 até 1.0) em um vetor com tamanho determinado:

```
def gerar():
   from random import random
   tamanho = int(input())
   resposta = [0.0] * tamanho
   for i in range(tamanho):
       resposta[i] = random()
   return resposta
```

Answer (score 2):

Use o metodo Random combinado com alguma classe do mesmo.
ex:

```
import random

num = int(input('O computador pensou em um numero entre 0 e 5, você é capaz de advinhar? '))
sorteio = random.randint(0, 5)

if num == sorteio:
    print('Parabens, o numero pensando pelo computador foi {}, o mesmo do seu!!!'.format(sorteio))
else:
    print('Que pena, você nao acertou!!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Para gerar números aleatórios em Python 3, você pode usar a biblioteca "**random**". Aqui está um exemplo para gerar um número inteiro aleatório entre 0 e 9:

```
import random
print(random.randint(0, 9))
```

Você também pode gerar números flutuantes aleatórios com a função "random.uniform()", por exemplo:

```
import random
print(random.uniform(0, 1))
```

Caso queira especificar a precisão, você pode usar a biblioteca "decimal" para especificar a precisão do número flutuante gerado pelo random.uniform(). Por exemplo, aqui está como gerar um número flutuante aleatório com duas casas decimais:

```
import random
import decimal

D = decimal.Decimal

def random_float_with_precision(precision=2):
    # Escolha um número flutuante aleatório no intervalo [0, 1)
    random_float = random.uniform(0, 1)
    # Formate o número com a precisão desejada
    formatted_float = format(D(random_float), f'.{precision}f')
    return float(formatted_float)

print(random_float_with_precision())
```